# Como inserir dados em duas tabelas diferentes com o mesmo form?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, formulário

Tenho um formulário dinâmico em que as perguntas vêm de uma tabela da base de dados, algumas perguntas têm resposta de escolha múltipla que também vêm da base de dados. mas outras perguntas são de texto.
Ao fazer o submit necessitava que as resposta de escolha múltipla fossem para uma tabela e as resposta de texto fossem para outra tabela.

Como faço para diferenciar as resposta que vêm da checkbox e enviar para a tabela x e as resposta de texto para enviar para a tabela y?

Segue um esquema (um pouco tosco mas com a informação que acho relevante) da BD

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado

Comment: Como está a modelagem do seu banco? Até poderia explicar, mas creio que seria melhor você mostrar sua modelagem pra resposta ser mais adequada ao seu banco.

Comment: Diego Felipe,Obrigado, já editei a pergunta e inseri um esquema parcial da base de dados, ou seja eu na hora de fazer o submit necessito pegar nas respostas as perguntas que sao do tipo texto para a tabela (tblClienterespostaTxt) e nas resposta múltiplas que são checkbox para a outra tabela (tblClienteRespostaPre)